# How to transfer items from a quarry to a computer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack

I was planning on making a digital miner but my brother insisted that we make a quarry. Now I need to find a way to move items directly and automatically from the quarry to my computer. I have tried import buses and export buses but I don't understand how they work. I need a simple guide of how to do this.

Answer (score -2):

"Minecraft FTB Infinity Ep06 M.E. System fed from Quarry!":

Comment: You should summarise the main points of the video in you answer. That way, everyone can see directly what information they need (and if the video is taken down or something the information is still here).